# How to insert one column id (which is primary key) to different table?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I copy country table id into, client_country table, so in client_country table two entry is there (clientID, countryID)

Note: we can provide client id as hardcoded or with where condition.

My Query:

```
INSERT INTO Client_Country (clientId,countryId)
    VALUES   ((SELECT id FROM Client WHERE  name="Ey GLOBAL"), 
              (SELECT id from Country ));
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: MySQL or oracle?

Comment: And what's correlation between client and country? Show some sample data and what's expected result?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect a query to be using `INSERT . . . SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO Client_Country (clientId, countryId)
    SELECT cl.id, co.id
    FROM Client cl JOIN
         Country co
         ON cl.name = 'Ey GLOBAL' AND
            co.name = ?;
```

The `co.name = ?` is because it is unclear how  you are choosing the country.  If you want all countries for each client, leave out that condition.

Comment: sir i want all country

Comment: @PunitShukla . . . Then just remove the condition on `co`, as explained in the answer.